# Getting string characters in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string in ruby whose initial characters would be numbers and the last character would always be a letter. Some of the examples are: `2C, 1P, 45H, 135D.`

I want to get an array which would have 2 objects, first would be the number and second would be the character.

```
Eg: for 2C, array would be [2, C]
    for 45H, array would be [45, H]
    for 135D, array would be [135, D]
```

I tried `my_string[/(\d+)([A-Z])$/].split(//, 1)`, but it gives me an entire string in an array. Like ["2C"], ["45H"]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try splitting by [`(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])`](http://regex101.com/r/aN9vD3) instead...I can explain and post as answer if it works.

Comment: Okay let me try and will let you know on the result

Comment: It gave me an empty array

Comment: I did my_string[/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])/].split(//,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do some quick Googling to see how to use Ruby's split, but here is how you want to do it:

```
print '2C'.split(/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])/);
// ["2", "C"]
```

The [expression](http://regex101.com/r/aN9vD3) works by doing a lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) and a lookahead (`(?=...)`).  This means we will match the spot that has a digit to the left and a letter to the right.

Comment: Oh you using regex directly inside split. Hmm nice ways. Let me give it a try.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped -- short and sweet :)

Comment: Ah, using Ruby's split() is easier than I thought. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
'150D'.scan(/\d+|\w/)
# => ["150", "D"]
```